# Running a trained model

Tags: r, knn, model-fitting

This is a very basic question but I am struggeling with this.Also, I could not find out answer of this:

I have a trained KNN text classifier as

```
knn.pred <- knn(modeldata[train, ], modeldata[test,] , cl[train], k = 5, use.all = TRUE)
```

But I am not sure how i can give new input (not part of train/test data) and get it classified.

Comment: Can't you just substitute your new input for `modeldata[test,]`, assuming that the new input contains all the required columns with the expected names?

Comment: checkout this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-knn-classifier-to-predict-whether-the-price-of-stock-will-increase/

Comment: I tried that but I always get same Category.. I was not sure if what I did was right. Will share sample code